# Build Qt and transfer on another PC: possible?

Tags: qt, mingw

I'd like to know if it's possible (and how) to build Qt 6.6.2 open source for Windows (using MinGW) and distribute the built result on others Pc.
Someone can give me an help?

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @chehrlic deployment is valid also for the entire Qt just built?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. This is basically what the Qt installer does. Of course, you should ensure that the compilers used on the target machine are compatible with the ones used to build Qt.

Comment: I think the question is about custom Qt build itself not the project build? Also possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can build and install Qt on one machine and copy whole directory to another machine, but path must be the same on both machines. This is because qmake need to know where necessary tools are located in order to work.

If you want to store Qt at different path on second machine you need to run `qmake -set <prop> <value>` with appropriate properties and values. You can obtain properties and values running `qmake -query`.